# System Crontab or Root Crontab

Tags: sudo, cron, root

System crontab:

```
/etc/crontab
```

Root crontab:

```
sudo crontab -u root -e
```

Which way is preferred? As they all run tasks within administration privilege.

Answer (score 29):

`/etc/crontab` is the system wide crontab.

The format of `/etc/crontab` is like this:

```
# m h dom mon dow user      command
*   *  *   *   *  someuser  echo 'foo'
```

while `crontab -e` is per user, it's worth mentioning with no `-u` argument the crontab command goes to the current users crontab.  You can do `crontab -e -u <username>` to edit a specific users crontab.

Notice in a per user crontab there is no 'user' field.

```
# m h  dom mon dow  command
*   *   *   *   *   echo 'foo'
```

An aspect of crontabs that may be confusing is that root also has its own crontab.  e.g. `crontab -e -u root` will not edit `/etc/crontab`  See [Configuring cron](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-cron.html).

In Linux distros, per user crontabs are typically stored in: `/var/spool/crontabs/<username>`

**References**

https://superuser.com/questions/290093/difference-between-etc-crontab-and-crontab-e

Comment: As [Congiruring cron](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-cron.html) says: there is usually no need to create a user crontab for root.   Is that true? I mean the standard way is to edit the /etc/crontab, am I right?

Comment: There is no "standard" way, thus you can have both files. I usually edit root's crontab and avoit `/etc/crontab` just becaused I am used to `crontab -e`

Comment: This is useful information but it doesn't answer the actual question: should you use system crontab or root crontab?

Answer (score 11):

/etc/cron.d (and its siblings cron.daily/weekly/monthly) is preferred for all system crontabs. You shouldn't need to touch /etc/crontab.

It's essential to separate cron entries in multiple files based on their functionality if you are planning to manage or automate things. Files under /etc/cron.d can be easily managed by packages or configuration management tools like puppet and chef. Root's crontab OTOH is practically un-maintainable by anything other than humans.

So in short, for system stuff, you can use /etc/cron.*. If there's something you would like the root user to do, then use root's crontab. /etc/crontab should be left untouched and managed by a package.

Comment: You don't explain why root's crontab should be preferred to /etc/crontab. They're both single files so maintenance issues should be the same for each. It's also worth noting that scheduling can be much more granular in a crontab file than in the cron.* directories.

Comment: @CalumHalpin I think that's covered by fleet automation like puppet or chef being better able to manage independent files than lines within a file. Also `/etc/cron.d/job-name` files DO let you specify a just as granular schedule for the job; along with setting variables like which SHELL to use, which USER / LOGNAME, which MAILTO address, which HOME, which PATH etc etc.
It ALSO depends on your distro's cron. BSD derived, vixiecron… etc. Which is why there's a manual for the details.